# Cloudwatch Metric to indicate flakyness/intermittent failures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an end to end testing suite that publishes AWS Cloudwatch metrics of all test runs. For example I have a namespace called "Test" under which we have dimensions "ClassName, TestMethodName" and a metric called "Failed" which will be either 0 or 1.

The suite depends on a variety of test environments being up and running so amount of flakiness (or occasional failures) is expected. What I would like is a "metric" for each "ClassName, TestMethodName" which tells you how many times in the last N runs (percentage?) this test has failed effectively indicating flakiness levels.

Can someone suggest how I would go about achieving this?

Comment: I imagine you could have a second metric "Run" and use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to compute the proportion of "Failed" during a given period.